# PyCharm Professional how to get jinja comment color working?

Tags: pycharm, syntax-highlighting

I try to change the color of Jinja comment syntax as below snapshot though it doesn't get effect.

@1 The sample Jinja comment

@2, @3 the new color to set as green

After clicking OK/Apply, the color remain unchanged.

How can we get it work?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15750552/248616 maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Switching to **Jinja language template** as guided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15750552/248616); we need Professional edition to get this feature i.e. not available in Community version.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also have question for the comment color, because it was too dim to read comfortably. Try this: e.g. Select: Line comment ---> Click: the color box on the right pannel

[image]

[image]