# Jinja2 for PyCharm?

Tags: python, django, pycharm, jinja2

I am new to both Python and Django. I am following a tutorial where the teacher is using Jinja in Visual Studio. I tried to download it from plug-ins in PyCharm, but there is nothing called Jinja.

Is there any way I can use Jinja in PyCharm? Is there any alternative?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does PyCharm support Jinja2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750551/does-pycharm-support-jinja2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, this is a PyCharm professional feature (see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/templates.html)).

But for the professional version and as mentioned in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-1032, there is already Jinja support in PyCharm. You can set it (if not already recognized) via:

```
Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Template Languages
```

[image: Template Languages Settings]

And optionally add other file extensions (if Jinja files are not saved as `.html`) in:

```
Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types
```

[image: File type extension settings]

If you're working on Flask/Django or similar, don't forget to declare the *Template Folder* in:

```
Settings/Preferences | Project: <project name> | Project Structure
```

[image: Django template folder settings]

If the setup is done (it is possible that you don't have to setup anything, because everything is working out of the box), you can see that Jinja2 is detected and working, e.g.:

[image: Live example of using Jinja]

Comment: Thank you so much for your edit and answer. But I can't see the Template Languages section in my PyCharm. Please check this: https://prnt.sc/ufvxxk

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. This is only for the professional version, sadly. Maybe you can get it for free, see https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/buy/#discounts?billing=yearly (I am not affiliated with PyCharm.)?

Comment: ops! I may have to try Visual studio to see if they have it free. Thank you for your help though. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I was not available for some time. Thank you so much for your help, Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, the free version of Pycharm does actually execute Flask apps with Jinja templates and such. It's just that it can't do Jinja syntax highlighting.

Like, you'll see all your Jinja text as if it was plain HTML text when you're editing it, but then it will run it as Jinja anyways (I've used Jinja stuff such as `block`, `extends`, `include`, the `default` filter, `loop.index`... everything fine).

Comment: Thank you, good catch! That's missing in my answer!